# Inserting data in a table in PySpark Sql

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to insert a dataframe in a table. the dataframe what i have gives me output like this _

| Field | Value |
| --- | --- |
| id | 95 |
| name | N04 |
| parentId | 702 |
| parentExternalId | N7 |
| description | WAT.. |
| metadata | {_replir... |
| source | https://github.co... |
| Id | 43636 |
| createdTime | 2021-10-13 11:58:... |
| lastUpdatedTime |  |
| rootId | 6978 |
| agregates | null |
| dataset | null |
| labels | null |

And I have multiple rows here. Now I am trying to insert this data in one of the table which has columns as (PointID, Name, PointParentID, desc). I would like to insert Id column in PointID, name in Name, parentID in PointParentId and description in desc. How can I do this using pyspark sql. I tried below command and it works in inserting a single data in a table with a single column.

```py
df = spark.sql("Insert into `Utilities_66_Demo`.`UtilityProduct` values('Hi')")
df = spark.sql("Select * from `Utilities_66_Demo`.`UtilityProduct`")
df.show()
```

Same way I have table with 4 columns defined above and a dataframe where I need to insert data to.
But how can i insert a data completely in single call from the dataframe whose output I have shown above. the dataframe I got is from this code:

```py
dfSourceAssets = spark.read.format("xyz.spark.v1") \
   .option("type", "assets") \
   .option("tokenUri", sourceTokenURI) \
   .option("clientId", sourceClientID) \
   .option("clientSecret", sourceClientSecret) \
   .option("baseUrl", sourceBaseURL) \
   .option("project", sourceProject) \
   .option("scopes", sourceScopes) \
   .load()
```